# How to drill down to a box plot using highchairs

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use highchairs to drill down to  box plot. Essentially, I would like to have a bar plot and when I click on that bar plot it opens up  a box plot across multiple categories. However, it does not work.. I can drilldown to a line or a bar but not a box plot. I am new to JS and any help will be much appreciated. I tried this based on the jsfiddle.net and the link to my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/ur1ekkp6/147/. The code from that link Is posted below.

```
    // Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'boxplot'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Basic drilldown'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Animals_all',
    data: [{
      name: 'animals',
      y: 5,
      drilldown: 'animals'
    }, {
      name: 'animals2',
      y: 4,
      drilldown: 'animals2'
    }],
    type: 'bar'
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      type: 'boxplot',
      id: 'animals',
      data: [
        //[0, 50083.75, 55442.63, 69483.10, 112070.49, 150382.94],
        [0, 50083.75, 55442.63, 69483.10, 112070.49, 150382.94],
        [1, 46943.39, 64711.77, 90199.38, 117247.03, 144365.60]
                ]
            }, {
            id: 'animals2',
            data: [{
            x: 1,
            low: 137.454800,
            q1: 193.180600,
            median: 239.781500,
            q3: 268.534200,
            high: 307.995100
            //[0, 50083.75, 55442.63, 69483.10, 112070.49, 150382.94]
            //[0, 50083.75, 55442.63, 69483.10, 112070.49, 150382.94]
            //[2, 46943.39, 64711.77, 90199.38, 117247.03, 144365.60]//
          }, 
          [0, 50083.75, 55442.63, 69483.10, 112070.49, 150382.94]
            ]
        }]
      }
});
```

Essentially, what I am looking for is similar to their demo of a combination plot

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/across-types/

where they drill down from column to pie....instead I want to drill down to a box plot.

Comment: Check the console - you receive the error. If you want to use a box plot series, you need to include highcharts-more module. http://jsfiddle.net/ur1ekkp6/153/

Comment: this is awesome, can you show me how you linked the errors back to the missing module. I got
`Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:240)
    at highcharts.js:314
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:29)
    at a.Chart.addSeries (highcharts.js:314)
    at a.Chart.q.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown (drilldown.js:13)
    at a.Chart.q.addSeriesAsDrilldown (drilldown.js:11)
    at drilldown.js:22
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:29)
    at a.Point.f.Point.doDrilldown (drilldown.js:22)`

Comment: also @morganfree if you post the above as an answer, I can upvote it :)

Comment: If you follow the link in the error to http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17, it tells you that **"The requested series type does not exist"**, and further, that *This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.* which leads to @morganfree's conclusion